# Is it possible to disallow muting test failures?

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

We have a static analyzer which runs regularly as a Teamcity test suite. We only want developers to whitelist vulnerability detections, not to mute them. Ideally, only the security team could mute these test failures. Is there an ACL we can set specifying who can and cannot mute test failures? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is "Mute / unmute problems in project" permission which controls it. It is granted to Project administrator role by default. Project developer role does not have it, but maybe the role was changed on your server.

Comment: Is it possible to set this on a per-test suite basis? We are ok with developers muting test failures elsewhere, just not for our static analyzer tests...

Comment: Permissions in TeamCity are per project. You probably can move this static code analysis build to some separate project where developers do not have permissions to mute problems.